# Fonts Loading issue on SharePoint 2016 in IE

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have this font rendering issue in my website see the image below. Any help would be very appreciated. Thank you

[image: Console Errors]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below article is relevant to same problem.

https://medium.com/@zikaitoh/css3111-and-css3114-issue-640e7d5e9163